# Counting occurrencies by row

Tags: r, count, apply

Imagine I have a data.frame (or matrix) with few different values such as this

```
test <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(c(-1,0,1),20, replace=T, prob=c(0.2,0.2,0.6))))   
test2 <- test
```

If I want to add extra columns with counts I could do:

```
test2$good <-  apply(test,1, function(x) sum(x==1))   
test2$bad <-  apply(test,1, function(x) sum(x==-1)) 
test2$neutral <-  apply(test,1, function(x) sum(x==0))
```

But If I had many possible values instead I would have to create many lines, it won't be elegant.

I've tried with table(), but the output is not easily usable

```
apply(test,1, function(x) table(x))
```

and there is a big problem,  if any row doesn't contain any occurrency of some factor the result generated by table() doesn't have the same length and it can't be binded.

Is there way to force table() to take that value into account, telling it has zero occurrencies?

Then I've thought of using  do.call or lapply and merge but it's too difficult for me.

I've also read about dplyr count but I  have no clue on how to do it.
Could anyone provide a solution with dplyr or tidyr?

PD:  What about a data.table solution?

Comment: There is certainly a better way but maybe `sapply(-1:1,function(y){apply(test,1, function(x) sum(x==y))})` can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could `melt` the dataset to long format after converting to `matrix`, get the frequency using `table` and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
library(reshape2)
cbind(test2, as.data.frame.matrix(table(melt(as.matrix(test2))[-2])))
```

---

Or use `mtabulate` on the transpose of 'test2' and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(test2, mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(test2))))
```

---

Or we can use `gather/spread` from `tidyr` after creating row id with `add_rownames` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
add_rownames(test2) %>%
     gather(Var, Val, -rowname) %>%\
     group_by(rn= as.numeric(rowname), Val) %>% 
     summarise(N=n()) %>%
     spread(Val, N, fill=0) %>%
     bind_cols(test2, .)
```

Comment: clever way, maybe a little bit convoluted

Comment: @JuanJosePiñerodeArmas  Thanks, but the code is just an one-liner.

Comment: I've tried the same with tidyr gather but it doesn't produce the same output, it doesn't generate the "row" number.

Comment: @JuanJosePiñerodeArmas  There is an option for `?add_rownames` in `dplyr`.  You can do that before `gather` from `tidyr`.

Comment: @Juanjo  I haven't tried it.  As this is not a question about tidyr, I am not testing it.

Comment: I  think add_rownames +gather don't work as expected

Comment: @Juanjo  Updated with the `gather` method.  It works for me though.

Comment: I've found the tidyr equivalent to your reshape2 code:  cbind(test2, as.data.frame.matrix(table(gather(add_rownames(test2), xx, valor,-rowname)[-2]))) .  I vote your solution because it's original, very different to mine and working.  Anyway I also like @jogo solution, it's even simpler.

Comment: @Juanjo I didn't use the `table(`..for tidyr as it is not that following the dplyr/tidyr syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `rowSums()`:

```
test2 <- cbind(test2, sapply(c(-1, 0, 1), function(x) rowSums(test==x)))
```

similar to the code in the comment from etienne, but without the call to `apply()`

Comment: This is now just a copy of @etienne's comment and doesn't address the question for arbitrary row contents

Comment: not totally: the code of etienne has the call to apply(). Neglecting this - you are right.

Comment: The advantage of c(-1, 0, 1) over unique(unlist(test))  is that the latter won't take into account some of the values if they don't appear, but you could still want the code to report it as zero occurrencies.

Comment: @Juanjo : till now there are 3 answers. You can decide to accept one or edit the question to describe what is not appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer using base R.

```
test <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(c(-1,0,1),20, replace=T, prob=c(0.2,0.2,0.6))))   
testCopy <- test

# find all unique values, note that data frame is a list
uniqVal <- unique(unlist(test))

# the new column names start with Y
for (val in uniqVal) {
    test[paste0("Y",val)] <- apply(testCopy, 1, function(x) sum(x == val))
}

head(test)
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 Y-1 Y1 Y0
# 1 -1  0  1  1  1  0 -1 -1  1   1   3  5  2
# 2  1 -1  0  1  1 -1 -1  0  0   1   3  4  3
# 3 -1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1 -1   1   2  6  2
# 4  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   0   0  7  3
# 5  0 -1  1 -1 -1  0  0  1  0   0   3  2  5
# 6  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   0  9  1
```